# Протестировать telegram-бота (python)

Tags: python, telegram-bot

Есть задача протестировать. Необходимо отправить боту сообщение (/start), но сделать это не через telegram, а внутри pycharm, т.е. сымитировать отправку сообщения пользователя. Как это можно сделать? Прошу объяснить как для последнего дурака, т.к. я в этой теме новичок.

Comment: https://core.telegram.org/#telegram-api